# SQL table to external content type (or types) - Suggestions on how I might do this

Tags: list, sql, external

I have an SQL table that has 11 columns.  I need to use what is in each column as a separate, independent drop down in a list item.  The columns and rows aren't related, there just grouped into one table as an extract from an oracle database.

So for instance, a list item would have 11 drop downs in which each drop down would have a selected value but they aren't related.

Do I need to make 11 different external lists that are columns in a list item?  I need to perform this using either SharePoint designer and/or Javascript.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be able to do is create External Data Columns.  I've never done it before myself, so take all this with a grain of salt, but it seems like there is a way to create a list column and have it connected to a single field of an external content type.

What you would need to do would be

- have your external content type set up and available on the site
- go to the list (all tutorials I've found say to create the columns on
  the list itself, not as a site column, and indeed when I went to Site
  Columns to create a new one, the "External Data" was not an option,
  but if I went into a list and tried to create a new column there, it
  was)
- create 11 external data columns, each one showing *only* the field
  you want for that column

I'm not sure what the controls actually look like for those types of fields, so you may not get drop-downs.

There's a couple tutorials [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-update-an-external-data-column-in-a-list-or-library-44eff2c5-8051-489d-989c-f5d09f527aee) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee559346(v%3Doffice.14)), and of course you can find many more online.

If you absolutely *must* have drop-down controls, something I would try might be to create the external content type, create a *single* external list, and then create lookup fields that lookup to the individual columns on the external list.  I have no idea if that would actually work, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try and let you know....